# Matlab: zero groups of non-zero elements in a matrix based on group size

Tags: matlab, matrix

Essentially I have binary, 3D image masks with the "1"'s in them in groups of various shapes and sizes spread throughout the mask. Working in matlab, I've got tools that allow me to convert this into a matrix, and what I'm looking to do is go through the matrix and zero blobs of 1's (i.e. adjacent sets of non-zero numbers which are surrounded by 0's) if the total size of that group is less than a given number of elements (say 30). Is there a pre-existing function that will do this, or am I going to need to get involved with kernels and the like?

As an aside, I'm still fairly new to Matlab so would really appreciate any answers given being written in a "for dummies" kind of style! Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, Matlab has a function for that: `bwareaopen`

```
maskWithOnlyBigObjects = bwareaopen(mask, 30);
```

This will eliminate all connected groups of 1's that are smaller than 30 1's. Note that by default, `bwareaopen` uses 26-connectedness, i.e. two 1's belong together if one is among the 26 possible neighbors in 3D, even if only corners are touching. If two 1's can only belong together if the faces of the voxels touch, use

```
maskWithOnlyBigObjects = bwareaopen(mask, 30, conndef(6));
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly. Thanks very much for the response!